# How to minimize Modern UI/Metro apps in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

How can I minimize a Modern UI app in Windows 8? I know I can use the Windows key or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, but there must be a way to do it with the mouse.

Comment: You can click and hold at the top edge of an application and drag it down as if you were swiping it away downwards.

Comment: That would shut it down completely Ivan. Not minimise/hide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are looking for a way to task switch Modern UI/Metro app, akin to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> but with the mouse, you can move your mouse to the upper right corner and then move it down. Up pops a Modern UI/Metro app task switcher UI.

Minimizing is a desktop metaphor and is not meaningful for Modern UI/Metro apps. Most Modern UI/Metro apps are automatically suspended when you switch away from them. Details found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx).

Comment: I just installed Visual Studio 2012 on W7 and I have a minimize button at runtime. If I had installed this on W8, would I not have a minimize button (does W8 prevent it)?

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 is a normal desktop application, and works much the same on W8 as on W7. The question is about Modern UI/Metro app, which are a completely new class of applications in Windows 8 which run outside the desktop.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Although it does seem to be a mixture of 'cultures' now - A desktop computer will have a 'desktop' and mixing this with the new approach could become quite disjointed I would guess. I'm looking forward to trying it. Thank you for your answer +1

Comment: It is a bit of a jarring transition. But, truth to be told, the Mordern UI/Metro apps are designed for 10in screen and touching. They don't make any sense on a big desktop computer with a mouse and keyboard. The other side of the coin is the desktop, which is a pain to use with fingers. So the usage bifurcates into only Modern UI/Metro apps on Windows tablets and only desktop applications on normal desktop and laptop computers.